# Open link on new tab not work on IE7-8 and safari all versions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Open link on new tab not work on IE7-8 and safari all versions ?

can i use javascript , jquery to do thst ?

```
<a href="example.php" target="_blank">
    CLICK HERE!!
</a>
<br><br>
<a href="example.php" target="_blank" style="target-new: tab;">
    CLICK HERE!!
</a>
```

Comment: Yes, you CAN also use javascript :) And note that `target-new: tab;` is not supported in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
target="_blank"
```

Should work in all browsers. If it's not working, then something else must be interfering with the click.